# Casual alternative words for habitat in the context of zoo?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Consider this hypothetical expression,

> The staff of a zoo tries to provide animals, a **habitat** very close to their natural environment.

The world habitat sounds too science text-book like or too business like to me. Could you suggest a more casual alternative?

Comment: But the rest of the sentence is textbook-like.  So "habitat" (which is the idiomatic word for the places that animals in a zoo live in) is the best word.  The comma after "animals" should be deleted or replaced with "with".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say "*home*".

As what @James_K has mentioned in the comments, "habitat" is perfectly fine as there is no need for a more "casual" alternative.

Comment: "Home" is good.  "nest" is not idiomatic in this sense. "niche" has more technical meaning than "habitat", so isn't casual.

Comment: No - as I said, the zoo provides the habitat/environment, the mother animal (or both parents) make/build the nest.